# Transfering a uploaded file from page to page

Tags: php, html, cakephp, post

My client wants to have a 3 page form. The first page allows the user to enter data including a uploaded file. the second page confirms this data. and the third page submits the data to the database and directories.

Via post, I can keep saving the data to a hidden input fields, thats no problem. My problem is the uploaded file. how do I hold that document from page to page ? I am using Cakephp but any advice would help, thanks

Comment: I'd have to question why you need 3 pages to present/validate/submit a form.  You really just need 1 page.  You present the page and when they click submit you validate.  If it doesn't validate you present the same page again indicating which fields were not valid.  As for the file you wouldn't upload it unless the entire form passed validation.

Comment: Have you ever done work for someone and they wanted something they you entirely disagree with ? Well this is one of them.

Answer (score 1):

You can always just create the illustion that the form is utilising three different pages. Use AJAX to accept and validate/request the user confirm their submitted data. If in this view they accept it initiate a POST to submit all that data.

You really don't need three physically different files to achieve this but you can still let it appear in three stages to keep your client happy.

Answer (score 0):

You just  upload the file to temp directory and keep the value in hidden variables just like other form data . If form successfully submitted then the image copy to desired location other wise  delete the image

Comment: what about files from the forms that weren't confirmed?

Comment: The server only stores the file temporary, by the time I reach the next page the file is no longer there.

Answer (score 0):

You can easily fake these 3 pages using CSS. Or even 2, as "third page" is actually a server script which has nothing to do with pages in the browser.

Just make your form, then put an event on the submit button which changes divs to whatever "confirmation page" he wants. and then actually send the form using a button on this page.

that's all

Answer (score -1):

An uploaded file is always held temporarily. The server env var should tell you where it is. In Ruby's rack it is stored in the params var. So I guess there is a similar params var in php which has a hash with all the necessary information.

Answer (score -1):

Since the file would be uploaded on the first step, one option is to put the file's **location** in a hidden input field along with the rest of the data (either there, or put it in the session). With CakePHP, if your file field looks somewhat like that:

```
<input type="file" name="data[User][image]" id="UserImage" />
```

Then you will be able to capture the location through

```
$location = $this->data['User']['image']['tmp_name'];
```

Which will correspond to something like **/var/tmp/xxxxxx**

On the last page, if the user confirms all the data, you just use **move_uploaded_file()** to put the file wherever you want on the server.

```
move_uploaded_file($location, '/new/location');
```

Comment: So your saying so long as I store the location which is tmp_name in a hidden file. I should be fine ?

Comment: I'm not sure if the file is guaranteed to stay in PHP's TMP directory across requests...

Comment: @Ivo Depends on where the site is hosted. In a typical linux environment, the tmp directory is cleaned only after a reboot (according to FHS), so it's unlikely that the file would disappear during the process. If, however, there are doubts, you can always make a custom _temp_ directory, where the files could stay for whatever period you like.

Comment: @numerical25 For security reasons, I'd recommend storing the location in a session variable, as opposed to a hidden form field.

Comment: My server only keeps the tmp file in the tmp directory during the duration of the post. once the page refreshes, the file is gone.